# Не получается посмотреть результат кода

Tags: sublime-text

Ребят помогите пожалуйста чайнику, уже не знаю что делать. Не могу посмотреть результат своего кода в браузере. Нажимаю в Sublime text 3 по нужному файлу Open In Browser и вместо результата он просто отображает код. Без разницы какой браузер. Что не так? Буду очень признателен за помощь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Дружище, спасибо за подсказку, но в папке у меня файл так и сохранен "index.html". Это когда я его в браузере открываю,к нему добавляется "txt"... Не мог бы подробнее описать как это исправить? =/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на расширение файла, у Вас оно `.txt` (`index.html.txt`).

**Переименуйте файл в** `index.html`.

UPD:
**Если не отображается расширение файла, то по пути:**
*Панель управления -> Параметры папок -> Вид -> Дополнительные параметры*
у свойства *`Скрывать расширения для зарегистрированных типов файлов`* снимите галочку.

Comment: Дружище, спасибо за подсказку, но в папке у меня файл так и сохранен "index.html". Это когда я его в браузере открываю,к нему добавляется "txt"... Не мог бы подробнее описать как это исправить? =/

Comment: Скорее всего, твой компьютер просто скрывает расширения файлов. Приглядись, когда ты наводишь курсор, в подсказке написано `Тип: Файл "TXT"`. Включить расширения можно в Панели управления, а именно: Параметры папок -> Вид -> Дополнительные параметры -> Скрывать расширения для зарегистрированных типов файлов (сними галку)

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, что прошло много времени, но всё-таки попробуй это.
Если у тебя Windows, тебе нужно включить показ расширений файлов.
http://netler.ru/ikt/windows7-extension.htm

Comment: Извините, а что даёт нового ваш ответ к [принятому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988154/217579)?